# Why is my JavaScript asynchronous function not running till everything else finishes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, asynchronous-javascript

I am having a bit of a hard time understanding how javascript asynchronous functions work. In my actual use case, the function in question is a 3rd part API call but a simple setTimeout function is a simpler way to reproduce my problem.

I expect the code infinity loop until the set time function is done and then exit the loop and continue the program. In this example I want/expect the output to be "in set timeout: 5", followed by "out of set timeout: 5" but instead it infinitely loops indicating that the setTimeout function never even runs.

I have also tried without the loop and putting `await` before `setTimeout(function()` but then it prints "out of set timeout: 1" followed by "in set timeout: 5".

TLDR: I want my code to use an asynchronous function in a synchronous fashion.

```js
async function doWork() {
  var a = 1
  setTimeout(function() {
    a = 5
    console.log(`in set timeout: ` + a)
  }, 1000)
  i = 0
  while (a == 1) {}

  console.log(`\nout of set timeout: ` + a)
}

doWork()
```

Comment: JavaScript is not multithreaded. As soon as it gets to the infinite loop, it will stay there until it finishes (I.e. never). You either want to call a function from the setTimeout or use await or something like that (depending on your case). “Asynchronous function in a synchronous fashion” makes me think await.

Comment: It would work with `while(a == 1) { await;  }`

Comment: " I want my code to use an asynchronous function in a synchronous fashion." that's entirely impossible.

Comment: @JonasWilms had the same idea, tried it; didn't work. I assume the next promise is prioritized over returning to the event queue and executing the function from the timeout.

Comment: @thomas in which environment? I think the spec does not define task priority, but the web spec does with it's microtasks/macrotasks (and NodeJS also has something like this)

Comment: @JonasWilms I just copied the snippet to an answer, made the change and ran it.

Comment: Yeah, browsers put Promise resolution into a "microtask queue" and setTimeout callbacks into a "macrotask queue", and microtasks always run before macrotasks. So a macrotask is needed, `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 0))` should do it then.

Comment: This does what you need:

`function doWork(val) {
return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('in setTimeout:' + val);
  }, 1000);
});
}

async function newFunc(){
  let a = 5;
  const res1 = await doWork(a);
  console.log(res1);
  a = 1;
  console.log('out of setTimeout:' + a);
}

newFunc();`